# Modal appearing after pressing browser back button

Tags: javascript, browser, modal-dialog, back-button

So, if my web application is called, a introducing modal appears. It (the modal) has a "close" button and a checkbox to never show this modal again.
This all works fine. After clicking on a link, a site with content opens, but if the user clicks a browser back button (back to the homepage), the modal appears again, even if the "never show again" checkbox has been checked.

I have no idea how to solve this, just know that is some javascript issue.
I googled this problem, could't find anything that is similar to this problem.
Any ideas?

Comment: The 'never show again' isn't being saved correctly, or it doesn't check the previous saved choice correctly on reload. But you'll need to provide more info: does the app use cookies, local storage, etc?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved this issue by not caching the introduction page..